# What practical advantages does Iran get from full membership in the Shanghai Cooperation Organisation over and above bilateral deals it has?

Tags: iran, shanghai-cooperation-organisation

Besides some (obvious) PR, what does full SCO membership mean for Iran that they don't get e.g. from their bilateral deals [with China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93China_25-year_Cooperation_Program) or [with Russia](https://www.reuters.com/business/energy/iran-russias-gazprom-sign-primary-deal-energy-cooperation-2022-07-19/)?

There is a somewhat [long article in Tehran Times](https://www.tehrantimes.com/news/476818/Iran-officially-joins-SCO) about Iran's recently acquired SCO membership, but it doesn't spell out much in the way of practical advantages. So what does Iran get in practice from joining SCO that it didn't have before?

Comment: TBH I'm not 100% that they've joined already. Reuters and CGTN (unlike Tehran Times) only say that they signed a memorandum for joining, but it seems that typically they''ll really join in a year or two after that https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/iran-signs-memorandum-joining-shanghai-cooperation-organisation-tass-2022-09-15/ https://news.cgtn.com/news/2022-09-16/President-Xi-meets-with-Iranian-President-Raisi-in-Samarkand-1dn0OQKFVmM/index.html